# jQuery Datepicker clone has opposite of expected effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, backbone.js, datepicker

I recently noticed something odd in jQuery-UI datepicker:

As seen [in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7T6yr/1/), a clone of a datepicker doesn't retain the events like you want, but an append does!

```
<p>Date:
    <div id="datepicker"></div>

    <p><p><p>
        <div id="clone"></div>

        <div id="append"></div>
</p>
```

js:

```
var obj = {
    ...
    onSelect:  function(thing) {
       console.log(thing);
        $(this).attr('data-thing',thing);
    }  
};

$("#datepicker").datepicker(obj);

$('#clone').append($("#datepicker").clone(true));

$('#append').append($('#datepicker'));
```

I had a case where each module has different sections on a page, each of which has settings (including date) that are kept the same within all sections.

Even with cloning the existing settings, removing the original, and appending to selected section, it messes up the callback, which has a "this" with a root (`$(this).parent().parent().parent()...`) of `null`, not window.

Is this something unexpected in the jQuery-UI picker, or am I going about this the wrong way? I have a feeling Backbone js may have a better way to keep data outside of the DOM, but is there a recommended pattern for something like this? Also, how does datepicker retain its events on append?

Comment: Calendars do not work - appending makes the month switch, day selector, and the callback to set "data-thing" to date correctly. Clone does not. Ironically, `.clone(true)` is usually how you're supposed to make event handlers work on copy - but when the div also contains datepicker, you can see the problem...

Comment: @muistooshort because a brand new one was initialized with some variables that may change, then change again... - I assume a backbone Model might be a solution?

Comment: @muistooshort That makes sense, is there a common Backbone pattern to "store all the state outside the picker and use that to initialize new ones"?

Comment: @muistooshort Do you have an example or tutorial link for a setup like that?